# Can I trigger a combo or a queuing action in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2, keyboard

I want to use some spells and items each one right after the other, or set a trigger as a combo in Dota 2.

I read a statement somewhere about holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, I tried using it to trigger a combo but I failed.

So, **is it possible to trigger a combo in Dota 2? If yes, how?**

Comment: Do you mean something like macro? OR you just mean to put things(actions) in queue to be exectued after each other?

Comment: I think using macros in steam games is not allowed, and yes about put thing in queue ;).

Comment: That's why I'm asking if THAT's what u want cause thne I could just answer that such thing aint allowed :D..

Comment: I've wrote you an answer, hope it's what you were asking about. I can't try it right now cause I don't have dota installed now, but if it's not what you meant tell me.

Answer (score 6):

**Combo** usually stands for a combination of certain actions you do in certain order and granting you extra bonus for that.

I don't think that's what you have in mind. You are probably asking about putting certain actions into **Queue** - so that they are executed in certain order after each other.

I've played DotA + DOTA2 for long time, but currently I'm having long break, anyway when I played it was possible to put certain actions(I'm not sure if you can include spells in this queue, it was mostly used for walking in certain path/circles) into queue **while holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**:

**Example:**

You want to walk certain way in woods, place a ward somewhere and go back.
All you have to do is to HOLD <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + click on some spots on the way where you wanna go, click on your ward HOLD <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + place ward on the spot, HOLD <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + click on place where you wanna go back to.

Now you release your <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and your hero should be already on it's way to the spot, place ward and come back.

If I remember how this worked ;).

> **Don't forget:** Whole queue can be canceled by clicking without holding <kbd>shift</kbd> anytime.
>   + If you are having issues with this working try to check your key binds in settings if you don't have <kbd>Shift</kbd> for different action.

Comment: Ok, hope it works as it did :P

Comment: Yes, queueing actions still works. Each action will start after the previous one finishes, and can include casting spells and using items (with targeting). Actions queued while channelling start at the end of the channel. E.g. as Tidehunter I could TP to a tower, then queue blink (target), ravage, and anchor smash. It might be hard to cancel if the opponents move, though, and if you take damage on arrival the blink will cancel and you might waste ravage! Queues are particularly useful for having illusions walk certain routes, or attack-move along a lane.

Comment: @Samthere They are incredibly useful for targeted abilities that follow up blinks or skillshots. Blink + shift-hex via sheepstick is virtually impossible to evade, hook + shift-dismember makes for quite some rage in pub games. And the worst that can happen if you miss the skillshot or your blink is down - you spend a second walking in the direction of your target.

Comment: @Ordous Agreed, it can be very strong, but it does take a little experience and care (e.g. not cancelling a channel because you wanted to cancel a queued ult).

Comment: Best answer should be marked as correct :-)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is **macros**.

Although *a bit unethical* macros are **allowed** in Dota 2 according to the [Dota 2 Dev Forums](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=180182).

According to [this](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Macros.htm) source:

> A macro is a series of scripted actions that is "played" upon demand.
>   The most common activity of a macro is to send simulated keystrokes
>   and mouse clicks to one or more windows. Such windows respond to each
>   keystroke and mouse click as though you had performed it manually,
>   which allows repetitive tasks to be automated with high speed and
>   reliability.

Some keyboards have fixed buttons for macros but you can set one in every keyboard. For more information check this [site](https://autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Thanks for tips, Note that in Dota 2 you have some spells and items those needs to select a target ;).